# Are Angular 2/3 Directives compatible with Angular 4

Tags: angular

I would like to use this Swipe Directive - https://github.com/gajus/angular-swing but it looks like it's not written for Angular IO (Angular JS 4)

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort at all.  First of all, there isn't an Angular 3;  second of all, the directive that you posted is for AngularJs, not Angular (these **are not** the same framework).

Answer (score 1):

This will most certainly **NOT** work with Angular 2+. From the documentation:

> AngularJS directive for Swing: A swipeable cards interface. The
>   swipe-left/swipe-right for yes/no input. As seen in apps like Jelly
>   and Tinder, and many others.

It is specifically for AngularJS, as in Angular 1.x. This can be confirmed by looking at the [source](https://github.com/gajus/angular-swing/blob/master/src/angular-swing.js) code. It's utilizing `$scope` and `$apply` as well as syntax for declaring Angular 1.x directives such as `link` functions.

```
function SwingStackController($scope, $element, $attrs, $parse) {
  // ...
}

SwingStackController.$inject = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$parse'];

function swingStack() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: SwingStackController,
  }
}
```

You could instead consider a library such as [HammerJS](http://hammerjs.github.io/) which libraries such as Angular Material 2 use for touch gestures.